# DocuSign - Template with 2 Roles - Last Recipient Can Add Fields to Document

Tags: docusignapi

I'm not sure if something has changed but I'm seeing something I haven't seen before. I have a simple DocuSign Template with 2 Roles and 2 Recipients. There are 3 sets of tabs for Sign Here, Date Signed and a Text tab for them to enter some text.

I create the Envelope and send it - the envelope looks like this:

```
    {
    "emailSubject" : "Please Sign the Agreement",
    "status" : "sent",
    "templateId" : "xxxxxxx",
    "templateRoles" : 
    [
        {
            "email" : "fred@flinstones.com",
            "name" : "Fred Flinstone",
            "roleName" : "Tenant",
            "routingOrder" : "1",
            "tabs" : {}
        },
        {
            "email" : "barney@rubble.com",
            "name" : "Barney Rubble",
            "roleName" : "Landlord",
            "routingOrder" : "2",
            "tabs" : {}
        }
    ]
}
```

The first recipient sees the Agreement and can Sign etc normally for their assigned tabs and finish, which sends it to the 2nd recipient. However they get a view that doesn't prompt them to sign etc like the first recipient, but instead they get a view similar to editing the Template. In the top left it says `Drag and drop fields from the left panel onto the document` and has a list of fields that can be dragged onto the document:

[image]

Once the fields are dragged the Finish button appears - I've never seen this and can't understand why this happens for the 2nd role/recipient and not the first. Previously it was the same for all recipients - they would simply be prompted to sign and enter the text field and not have to drag the fields onto the document etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, there are two views you can get when you sign:

1. Pre-defined view, which prompt user where to sign.
2. Tagger view, which looks like when you create a template or send an envelope. It's also known as "free-form" signing.

the latter view would show if no tabs (signing elements) were defined for the recipient. You need to check your template to ensure you places these elements for both recipient separately.
this can also be done from your code, by adding the tabs programatically.

Comment: I'm no longer able to reproduce this and haven't changed anything! Was very strange - not sure what was happening here, but it is back to normal today. There were definitely 2 roles with 2 sets of tabs defined in the Template for each role.